# Predict player win or lose, game theory question

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-theory

I am trying to solve [this question](https://www.spoj.com/problems/MAIN73/).

Problem Description: Given n*m grid, each cell is either empty(denoted by .) or have a stone(denoted by *).Two players take turn alternatively, and in each turn one can either:

1.shift an stone to its adjacent right cell, if that cell is empty

2.remove a stone completely from the grid.

We have to find which player will win.

Basically what my approach is that whenever the number of stones and possible moves to right are even/odd or vice-versa, the first player can always win as we can always reduce it to even-even which according to me is losing state.

But I am getting the wrong answer.
I cannot find where I am going wrong.

```
int main()
{
  int i,j,n,m,cnt,pos;
  char ch;
  while(true)
  {
      cin>>n>>m;
      if(n==0 && m==0)break;
      cnt=pos=0; //cnt store count of stones
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                cin>>ch;
                if(ch=='*')
                {
                    cnt++;
                    pos+=(m-j-1); // this stone can be moved to m-j-1 places to right
                }
            }
      }
      if(cnt==1 || ((cnt&1)!=(pos&1)))cout<<"Player with first turn Wins"<<"\n";
      else cout<<"Player with second turn Wins"<<"\n";
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the problem description in the question as text. Please use meaningful variable names.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are handling the terminating condition, where `n` and `m` are zero.  Also, you should pay attention to how the input is described.  If a contest-style question says how many _lines_, and even which _character_ is in what _position_ on a line, then if your code is not handling line-based input at all it should be a guaranteed fail for any input designed to check that... Well, that's how real contest questions work.  Maybe SPO doesn't test ability to follow specification though.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I have updated the description and variables.

Comment: You are not even testing whether the grid contains a stone, so you have no basis with which to know how many places a stone can be shifted in any direction.

Comment: @paddy The if(ch=='*) conditon handles it.

Comment: No it does not.  In typical contest-style, the question provides simple input examples designed to trick shallow thinkers into inventing substandard solutions.  What if you have a larger board with lots of stones on it?  Do you think that your `pos += j` trick is still valid?

Comment: @paddy I updated my code. Also if the grid contains no stone then 'Player with second turn wins' as both pos and cnt will be 0.

Comment: Not sure whether the code is counting moves correctly. `**.` seems like 2 moves, and 2 stones, but I think the code would count 3 moves and 2 stones.

Comment: @user3386109 I want to know the correct approach, my current approach is wrong,

Comment: You have the right approach, even-even is a losing state. For moves, you need to count how many moves it takes so that all the stones are to the right. For example, with `**.` it's two moves: `**.` -> `*.*` -> `.**`. With `*.**..` it's 7 moves: `*.**..` -> `*.*.*.` -> `*.*..*` ->  `*..*.*` -> `*...**` -> `.*..**` -> `..*.**` -> `...***`

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic problem with your algorithm, based on your logic, the person who moves first always wins. Let's say you have a 3x1 grid, and you have two stones, let the array be the following: {full, full, empty}, now in this case the first person to make a move would always lose, lets say he moves to the right it would become {full, empty, full} then the second person will move the other stone to the right, {empty, full, full} and then he has no choice but to remove the stone, and the second player would remove the other stone resulting in the finally array: {empty, empty, empty} hence the first player loses, if the first player were to remove a stone with his first move instead, the second player would remove the second one: again leading to the {empty, empty, empty} combination. So you cannot just assume the player who goes first always wins.

thanks,
Yun Fei Chen

Comment: What does cnt&1 and pos&1 supposed to do, I never seen those symbols before just saying....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_&